# How can I download dynamically the newest webrowser for firefox using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

The main goal is to download web browser which is compatible with the current one.

This approach work so well for chromium and it's what I want to achive for gecko :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install())
```

What to add to the below line to achieve the same results ? It doesn't work.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

Comment: Firefox isn't as picky about the driver version, so it shouldn't be a concern.  Just update it every once in a while.  (as a side note you can turn off the version checking for chromedriver so it doesn't shut you down when versions mis-match, just set environment variable "webdriver.chrome.disableBuildCheck", "true")

Comment: @pcalkins Omg, thank you so much !! I didnt know that I can turn off version checking. I didn't even think about googling if it's possible. I'm going to try :)